# Jquery ui `removeClass` doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

this is my HTML

```
<div id="c">
    <div class="base">
        <div class="cb out" id="red" data-color="Red">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="base">
        <div class="cb out" id="green" data-color="Green">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="base">
        <div class="cb out" id="blue" data-color="Blue">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to remove `out` class and add `in` class using jquery-ui with effect. This is the code:

```
    //focuse mouseower
    function fmo(element) {
        var $element = $(element);
        $element.removeClass("out");
        $element.addClass("in",300);
    }

    //blur mouseout
    function bmo(element) {
        var $element = $(element);
        $element.removeClass("in");
        $element.addClass("out",300);

    }
    function ready() {
        $(".cb").mouseover(function () { fmo(this); });
        $(".cb").mouseout(function () { bmo(this); })
        $(".cb").focus(function () { fmo(this); });
        $(".cb").blur(function () { bmo(this); });
    }
    $(function () { ready(); });
```

the code above doesn't work but if I remove jquery-ui reference and just use jquery to do the job with this code:

```
    //focuse mouseower
    function fmo(element) {
        var $element = $(element);
        $element.removeClass("out");
        $element.addClass("in");
    }

    //blur mouseout
    function bmo(element) {
        var $element = $(element);
        $element.removeClass("in");
        $element.addClass("out");

    }
    function ready() {
        $(".cb").mouseover(function () { fmo(this); });
        $(".cb").mouseout(function () { bmo(this); })
        $(".cb").focus(function () { fmo(this); });
        $(".cb").blur(function () { bmo(this); });
    }
    $(function () { ready(); });
```

it works. I don't know what to do but I really need help.
**update** 
this is my style(I think it may can effect the result)

```
<style type="text/css">
    .out {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 5px;
        background-color: #56a100;
        opacity: 0.5;
        margin: auto;
        width: 70%;
        height: 70%;
    }

    .in {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 5px;
        background-color: #56a100;
        opacity: 1;
        margin: auto;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .base {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
</style>
```

**I uploaded the code [here](http://ahmadalli.net/t/m/)**

Comment: nitpick: Your code is full of globals because you are not declaring var. Var is not optional.

Comment: @epascarello: I added `var` but there is no change to act. it's still not working

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee `var` wasn't the problem you are trying to solve, but it was still a problem

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: I know. and I edited the code

Comment: Are there any errors on the page? Are you sure jQueryUI is included properly?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker in [this page](http://jqueryui.com/download) I selected all items and downloaded the jquery-ui code. and I used inspect element chrome tools and there where no errors. I alse uploaded the page [here](http://ahmadalli.net/t/m/index.html)

Comment: [Working here](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/BXRcd/1/), make sure you included `jQuery ui` properly.

Comment: @SheikhHeera: now I added my styles [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BXRcd/2/) and it doesn't work correct!

Comment: [Is this what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/BXRcd/4/) ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera yes it is. but it doesn't work correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function(){ 
    $(".cb").on('mouseenter', function(){ 
        $(this).stop(1,1).removeClass("out").addClass("in", 300);
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function(){ 
        $(this).stop(1,1).removeClass("in").addClass("out",300); 
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/BXRcd/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get that second parameter on add/remove class?

Use queue, use chaining, and make functions to reuse code.

```
function helper (_elem, add, remove){
  var elem = $(_elem);
    elem.removeClass(remove).delay(300).queue(
     function(next){
        elem.addClass(add);
        next();
     }
  );
}

//focus mouseower
function fmo() {
  helper(this, "in","out");
}

//blur mouseout
function bmo() {
  helper(this, "in","out");
}

function ready() {
    $(".cb").on("mouseover focus", fmo).on("mouseout blur", fmo);
}
$(ready);
```

Comment: The second parameter is added by [jQueryUI's version of `addClass`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/addClass/):

Comment: I don't want `delay`!! I want `animate` with `addClass` method and Jquery-UI has it!